# css vs svg - формирование фигурных границ

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, border

Можно ли с помощью css сформировать блок `div` так, как он изображён на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. сверху прозрачный элемент (за ним будет виден фон), снизу - основной элемент,
как я понимаю - снизу обычный `background` у div
а сверху надо как-то сформировать с помощью `border`,
но как?

Comment: с помощью clip-path polygon можете  сформировать блок каким угодно образом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сети давно гуляют примеры реализации. Вот один из них:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #222;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background: white;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.tabs {
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
}

.tabs li {
  /* Makes a horizontal row */
  float: left;
  /* So the psueudo elements can be
      abs. positioned inside */
  position: relative;
}

.tabs a {
  /* Make them block level
       and only as wide as they need */
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Default colors */
  color: black;
  background: #ddc385;
  /* Only round the top corners */
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.tabs .active {
  /* Highest, active tab is on top */
  z-index: 3;
}

.tabs .active a {
  /* Colors when tab is active */
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.tabs li:before,
.tabs li:after,
.tabs li a:before,
.tabs li a:after {
  /* All pseudo elements are
       abs. positioned and on bottom */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Only the first, last, and active
     tabs need pseudo elements at all */

.tabs li:last-child:after,
.tabs li:last-child a:after,
.tabs li:first-child:before,
.tabs li:first-child a:before,
.tabs .active:after,
.tabs .active:before,
.tabs .active a:after,
.tabs .active a:before {
  content: "";
}

.tabs .active:before,
.tabs .active:after {
  background: white;
  /* Squares below circles */
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Squares */

.tabs li:before,
.tabs li:after {
  background: #ddc385;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.tabs li:before {
  left: -10px;
}

.tabs li:after {
  right: -10px;
}


/* Circles */

.tabs li a:after,
.tabs li a:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /* Circles are circular */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  /* Circles over squares */
  z-index: 2;
}

.tabs .active a:after,
.tabs .active a:before {
  background: #ddc385;
}


/* First and last tabs have different
     outside color needs */

.tabs li:first-child.active a:before,
.tabs li:last-child.active a:after {
  background: #222;
}

.tabs li a:before {
  left: -20px;
}

.tabs li a:after {
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs group">
  <li class=""><a href="#one">One</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#three">Four</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Round Out Tabs</h1>
</div>
```

По [ссылке](https://habrahabr.ru/post/128210/) подробно описан весь процесс. Правда добиться округления именно с прозрачным фоном скорее всего не получится. В этом случае необходимо смотреть в сторону `clip-path`.

Comment: в том, то и дело, что указанное решение не прозрачно (по сути изгиб формируем черным (в цвет фона) кругом) :(

Comment: Если фон белый, просто измените цвет круга. Только в случае наложения на цветастый фон возникнут проблемы. Во всех иных случаях поможет `png` изображение, `svg` или `clip-path`.

Comment: Алексей, фон к сожалению не белый, но более-менее однородный, поэтому этот номер прошел,

Но думаю все таки придется clip-path и svg использовать, но пока устраивает, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

### Решение SVG

Для решения подобного рода задач идеально подходит SVG. Графика на сайте должна быть векторной, так как векторное изображение имеет минимальный вес и по определению является адаптивным.

Для создания векторной фигуры вам понадобятся минимальные знания работы в векторном редакторе и несколько строчек кода `SVG`

**Преобразуем растровую картинку в векторную:**

Я постараюсь подробно изложить все шаги, чтобы даже люди, которые не работали в векторном редакторе, могли повторить эту работу на другом, своем примере.

*Данная техника подойдёт и для других целей,- например для создания
   патчей маски и `clipPath`*

Растровую картинку можно сразу загрузить в векторный редактор, но при этом способе возникает много нюансов с преобразованиями, с возможными последующими проблемами  масштабирования, стилизацией. Не будем пока рассматривать этот вариант, используем другую технику.

- Создание файла `svg` для загрузки растрового изображения в векторный
  редактор. 
  Изображение имеет размеры `500x500px`, поэтому `viewBox="0 0 500 500"`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="500" height="500"     viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ginL.png" x="2" width="99%" height="99%" />
 </svg>
```

- Открываем этот файл svg с помощью векторного редактора

И с помощью инструмента рисование кривых  Безье  -  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]  рисуем контур.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для более точного повторения контура необходимо сделать узловые точки "автоматически сглаженными"  Для этого удерживая `shift` щёлкаем по выбранным узлам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И с помощью рычагов управления узловых точек добиваемся совпадения контура с изображением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в векторном редакторе в формате `*.svg`
- Открываем файл в текстовом редакторе и копируем `<path>`
  Можно было бы использовать получившийся файл svg `inkscape`, но он слишком перегружен служебной информацией, а нам нужна всего лишь одна строчка с патчем, которую можно использовать и для решения  вопроса автора, а также в дальнейшем  для создания масок и клип патчей.

Ниже пример с необходимыми контурами, но пока без фона

```css
#Border {
 fill:#0090D0;
 stroke-width:2;
 stroke:#0090D0;
 }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="500" height="500"     viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
    <path id="Border" d="m1.1 111.5 174.8 0.6c0 0 3.6 21.7 7.8 31.7 4.9 12 11.7 23.5 20 33.4 5.9 7.1 12.8 13.6 20.9 18.1 16.7 9.3 39 17 54.8 17L495.4 211.7 497 495 2 495Z" />
 </svg>
```

- Добавляем фон

```css
 .container { 
   width:25%;
   height:auto;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikD0n.png);
 background-size:cover;
   }
 #Border {
 fill:#0090D0;
 stroke-width:2;
 stroke:#0090D0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
    
    <path transform="translate(0 35)" id="Border" d="m1.1 111.5 174.8 0.6c0 0 3.6 21.7 7.8 31.7 4.9 12 11.7 23.5 20 33.4 5.9 7.1 12.8 13.6 20.9 18.1 16.7 9.3 39 17 54.8 17L495.4 211.7 497 495 2 495Z" />
 </svg>   

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

реализовал полностью на css

```css
.popup-menu {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.popup-menu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: calc(25px + 2px);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: #0090d0;
}

.popup-menu li ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 65px - 25px);
  height: 25px;
  background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/white_texture.png) repeat top left;
  border-left: 25px solid #f9f9f9;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.popup-menu>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.popup-menu li ul li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 120%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-menu li ul li:hover {
  background: #199bd5;
}

.popup-menu li ul li span {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: BebasNeueRegular;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.popup-menu li ul li span div {
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.popup-menu li ul li span img.ddm-item {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

по сути вся соль в `.popup-menu  li  ul:after`
единственный недостаток - скругленная накладка сливается с фотоном, но если накрывает текст, то текст будет невидимым, хотя терпимо, но нет примера совершенству

все таки использование svg - это будет использование и css и svg - менее удобно, но результат будет конечно лучше, но svg придётся вставлять отдельно

Comment: вот работоспособный https://jsfiddle.net/bp2j3pdk/
в тот раз привел именно код css без содержимого для чего этот код нужен

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, цитата из Мастера и Маргариты "Никогда и ничего не просите! Никогда и ничего, и в особенности у тех, кто сильнее вас. Сами предложат и сами все дадут!"

И кроме того - я не 100% времени в сети, появился, прочитал, ответил, оценил, если совет ПРИГОДИЛСЯ - разве не так?

Comment: может лучше сразу по законам зоны,- "Не верь, не бойся, не проси!"